# What is this kind of Highlight for the hair called?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history

[image: hair highlight]

I'd like to know what's this type of hair highlight called?

In the application Koikatsu, it is called "lighting" highlight.
I am wondering if this is the correct name?

Comment: I've been searching all around, still no official name for that kind of highlight. Danbooru doesn't specify it.

Comment: In Japanese there is word ツヤベタ(tsuyabeta) though it does not specifically refer to the 'lighting'. It rather means paint black the hair with the expression of luster. (See [this](https://esinote.com/guide/body/glossy-hair) for example).

Comment: What about "zigzag" highlight?

Comment: I suppose it is simply a type/style of luster. ツヤベタ just encompasses painting the hair with highlight.